# How to capture "Display advertisement" use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

What kind of use case it would be for to "show ad in part of the view"? Who could be the actor to relate with? User or System? As user has no specific goal to see ads, i am wondering what is the best way to capture this in use case diagram?

Any assistance will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think "Display advertisement” is not a use case of its own but a [Cross-cutting_concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)
that can be attached to many different use-cases:

from [Use_case@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case)

```
    a use case is a list of steps, 
    typically defining interactions between a role [...] and a system, to achieve a goal.
```

the end-user does not visit a car-webportal to see advertisments but to achive a goal: i.e. find infos about a certain type of car.

Showing advertisments is a Cross-cutting feature.

The goal of the car-webportal is

- to attract car-entusiasts
- and to make money by selling car-related ads.
- the more car-entusiasts visiting the website the more money they make.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it would look very much like any other use case.

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409432.aspx

In the above diagram, substitute "Advertiser" for "Restaurant," and "User" for "Customer."  Change one of the circles to "Serve Advertisement."

Comment: Say, if ads are stored through back office system and made available for my system in the db. Now my system is to show and keep rotating the ad. In "My system" use case diagram how to capture this use case? I guess in this scenario there is no "Restaurant" system directly interfacing "My system". Thanks.

Comment: Somebody has to provide you with the ads.